# Why do model's layer shape is (1000,) instead of (1000) in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(1000,)))
```

The sample code is up there. I assume that's how numpy works but when I tried with numpy, both definition give the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input_shape` argument in Keras takes in a `tuple` of `int` objects which define the input dimensions for the Layer or Model. See more on Tuples [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples).

> A tuple is a sequence of immutable Python objects.

For a clearer understanding, study the code below:

```
>>> x = ( 1 )
>>> y = ( 1 , )
>>> x[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
>>> y[0]
1
>>> print( x )
1
>>> print( y )
(1,)
>>>
```

The object `( 1 )` is treated as a single Python `int` object. Hence, we cannot subscript it or access items as we do in a Python `list`. Whereas `( 1 , )` indicates that a `tuple` with a single element is to be created. This tuple is subscriptable like a list.

Also, note the difference in how Python prints both the objects.

> A Keras `input_shape` argument requires a subscriptable object in which the size of each dimension could be stored as an integer.

Hence, we use `( 1000 , )` instead of `( 1000 )`.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Very clear explanation without telling me to google it first.